# IntelliJ IDEA does not recognize named query with Spring: 'Cannot resolve query'

Tags: java, xml, hibernate, intellij-idea

Sure, here's the translated question for Stack Overflow:

---

Hello!

I have a problem with using named queries in my **Spring** and **IntelliJ IDEA** project. In my project, I'm using named queries defined in XML files to avoid hardcoding queries in the code. However, **IntelliJ IDEA** doesn't recognize the named query and highlights it as an error saying "**Cannot resolve query 'Order.customNamedQuery'**".

I've checked that all the necessary dependencies are included, and the query files are in the correct location. I've also made sure that I specified the path to the query files in the EntityManager factory settings.

Here's a simplified version of my code:

```java
@Override
public boolean hasCustomSupport() {
    Query query = em.createNamedQuery("Order.customNamedQuery");

    return JpaQueryUtils.getFirstOrDefault(query, false);
}
```

And here's the XML file with the definition of the named query (Order.xml):

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<entity-mappings xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/orm"
                 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                 xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/orm http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/orm_2_0.xsd"
                 version="2.0">
    <named-query name="Order.customNamedQuery">
        <query>
            <![CDATA[
                -- Your custom query goes here --
            ]]>
        </query>
    </named-query>
</entity-mappings>
```

In order to see the constipation in the spring, I use

```java
LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean factoryBean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
FactoryBean.setMappingResources(setmappingresources());
```

```java
public string[] setmappingresources()
{
returns a new string[]{
"com/example/projectName/model/Order.xml",
...
}
```

I would like to understand why IntelliJ IDEA doesn't recognize the named query and how to fix it. I would appreciate any help!

Comment: What version of the IDE do you use? Can you upload a demo project to https://uploads.jetbrains.com and share the id of the upload here? I'll check it.

Comment: @Koyasha IntelliJ IDEA 2023.2.4 (Ultimate Edition)